# Using object's overloaded istream in another class C++

Tags: c++

I have a class called `Length` which holds hours, mins and secs. It has an overloaded `>>` operator for parsing input to the object:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& is, Length &t) {
    char c1, c2;

    int hours, mins, secs;

    if (is >> hours >> c1 >> mins >> c2 >> secs) {
        if (c1 == c2 == ':') {
            t = Length(hours, mins, secs);
        }
        else {
            is.clear(ios_base::failbit);
        }
    }
    return is;
}
```

Now I'm trying to write a class, which holds a `Length`, and a `Title` (for movies):

```
class Movie {
    string title;
    Length length;

public:
    Movie();
    Movie(string title, Length length);
    string getTitle() const;
    Length getLength() const;
    operator int() const;
};

inline Movie::Movie() {
    this->title = "New Movie";
    this->length = Length();
}

inline Movie::Movie(string title, Length length) {
    this->title = title;
    this->length = length;
}
```

I'd like to overload this `>>` operator too, to get input converted to a `Title` and a `Length` object.

Is there a way to use the `>>` overload I wrote in `Length`, inside the `Movie` overloaded `>>` operator? All I've got so far:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& is, Movie &d) {
    string title;
    Length length;
    /*Not sure how to code this*/
    return is;
}
```

Comment: not really clear what is the problem. What happened when you tried? What is wrong about `is >> d.length;` ?

Comment: You can just reuse the overloaded operator for `Length`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes.. how? That's what I'm asking

Comment: `is >> d.length; `?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to use the >> overload I wrote in Length, inside the
>   Movie overloaded >> operator?

Yes all you need to do is to call it, as in

```
istream& operator>>(istream& is, Movie &d) {
    string title;
    Length length;
    is >> title >> length;
    d = Movie(title,length);
    return is;
}
```

However, you dont need this additional instance. There already is a `title` and a `length` in the `d` you pass to the operator. You better make the operator a friend of `Movie` (via adding `friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&,Movie&);` to the declaration of `Movie`). Then you can write

```
istream& operator>>(istream& is, Movie &d) {
    is >> d.title >> d.length;
    return is;
}
```

For more details on operator overloading see here: [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)

Comment: What happens if my title is more than one word long? `>>` seems to only be grabbing the first word of the string. Do I need to handle this manually with a loop for example?

Comment: @eddiewastaken how do you know where the name stops? It one line per entry in the file?

Comment: it stops at the end of the line